# NodeJS Streams: Readable.pipe() doesn't send data immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, nodejs-stream

From what I understood about streams, `Stream.Readable.pipe()` should pipe the data as soon as it receives it.

I am trying to implement my own streams but the output is not as expected.

```js
const { Writable, Readable } = require("stream");

const writable = new Writable();
writable.data = [];
writable._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
  writable.data.push(chunk.toString());
  console.log(chunk.toString());
  next();
};

const readable = new Readable({
  read() {},
});

readable.pipe(writable);
readable.push("hi");
writable.write("ho");
writable.write("ho");
console.log(writable.data);
```

The output of this code is

```
ho
ho
[ 'ho', 'ho' ]
hi
```

The pipe is writing to the stream later. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write to the stream and not call directly to the write method of `writable`

```
const { Writable, Readable } = require("stream");

const writable = new Writable();
writable.data = [];
writable._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
    writable.data.push(chunk.toString());
    next();
};

const readable = new Readable({
    read() { },
});

const stream = readable.pipe(writable);
stream.write("hi");
stream.write("ho");
stream.write("ho");
console.log(writable.data);
```

//[ 'hi', 'ho', 'ho' ]